# About closed linear operators defined on a subset of a Banach space into a Banach space?

Tags: operator-theory

I have this weird theorem here:

If $A$ is a closed linear operator from Banach space $X$ into Banach space $Y$ i.e. $A:X\rightarrow Y$ (please take note that $A$ is closed but not necessarily bounded) and $D_A\subset X$ is the set on witch $A$ is defined and is a set of second category in $X$ Then proof that $D_A=X$

This is so weird, why would the domain of a linear operator be restricted by the fact that $A$ is closed?

Comment: Using the closed graph theorem you can reformulate the theorem as follows: let $A$ be closed and $D_A$ be of the second category. Then $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Ok so how would this help?

Comment: See if the proof of one of those standard operator boundedness theorems involves the Baire category theorem...  Note adoion has not been back for over a year...